# How to pull in employee service rates from Sheet 2 and sum in Sheet 1 according to services offered per month?

Tags: excel, google-sheets

The goal is to get the total pay to Employee 1 for January to show up on Sheet 1 in cell C13.

Same with Employee 1 / February in cell D13. And same for Employee 2.

This formula should pull from Sheet 2. In the example of Employee 1, it needs to:

1. Detect the Employee 1 rates per service in Sheet 2 (i.e., search row 1 for "Service 1" or "Service 2", then retrieve employee rates for that service)
2. Search C2:C4 in Sheet 1 to see what services are offered in January
3. Sum the Employee 1 service rates for Service 1 or 2 based on the services offered in that month (two rates should be combined if more than one service is offered in month)
4. Return sum in C13

Sheet 1:
[image]
Sheet 2:
[image]

I tried vlookup as well as index and match, but three hours in, I haven't made much progress.

Thanks in advance for any and all help!

--

After all of the work below, we arrived at

```
=SUMPRODUCT(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A13,'Sheet 2'!A11:K,IF(RIGHT(C2:C4)="1",{2;2;2},IF(RIGHT(C2:C4)="2",{5;5;5},IF(RIGHT(C2:C4)="3",{8;8;8},IF(RIGHT(C2:C4)="4",{11;11;11},)) )),0)))
```

This seemed like it was working until I moved Employee 1 from one row to the next. This formula requires the values to be in the same row, and my values will not always be in the same row, depending on the scenario.

Comment: How can you tell if "Service 1" and "service 2" are for January or February?

Comment: Cells C2:C4 and D2:D4 on Sheet 1 show you which services are provided in which month.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C13:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A13,'Sheet 2'!A11:E,IF(RIGHT(C2:C4)="1",{2;2;2},IF(RIGHT(C2:C4)="2",{5;5;5},)),0)))
```

Try CSE ,If in Excel.

Comment: I tried it. I'm not sure what I'm missing, but the total came out to 2400. If the only services selected for January in Sheet 1 are "Service 2", then the result should be 800 since Employee 1 gets $800 for Service 2 and there are no other services selected. Thanks a lot for your help. Not sure what I'm missing. I'll keep playing with it. I'm in Google Sheets.

Comment: Thanks for everything. Still not working. Formula returns "#VALUE!" and error message reads, "Error
Function IF parameter 1 expects boolean values. But 'E' is a text and cannot be coerced to a boolean."

Comment: I'm also getting a second error: "IF only takes 3 arguments, but this is argument 5." Not sure if that's helpful at all.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13cJUIY5oeS4V_MRUVHg0fKQ2icAxRMioOYa9-RjlHFk/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Seems really close. Trying to add another option to the services: "Service Three". I tried to change the range to include column H, and also tried to add IF(RIGHT(C$2:C$4)="Three",{8;8;8},) (totally guessing here—I have no idea if this is how it works). That didn't work. How would I go about adding an additional service that doesn't include a number in the title?

Comment: I'm open, but could use some guidance on how to approach testing the functions. Not sure how to test them "step-by-step", as you say. Thanks for your help so far.

Comment: Thanks I'll give it a try.

Comment: So I tested all of the functions in the manner you mentioned. I figured out that RIGHT(C$2:C$4)="Three" doesn't work because "Three" is too many characters for the default setting in RIGHT. If I change the count, then I can use "Three". So that's cool to understand. I am still unclear on {2;2;2} and {5;5;5}. Not sure what they are doing, since they would normally populate the rows below with the respective numbers.

Comment: Also, I tried to change the order of the employees on sheet 2 (ie, I put Employee 1 in row D12, and Employee 2 in row D11), and the formula seems to be combining Emp 1 and Emp 2 wages, rather than finding and combining Emp 1 wages.

Comment: vlookup looks for a specified value the first column of a range and returns a value in a cell a specifed number of cells to the right. It's important that your original range includes the total number of columns to look to the right. IF inside of an ARRAYFORMULA allowed me to search multiple columns for a matching value and to return the value if found and/or return another statement ("No") if not found. The results were duplicated for each column in the range.

Comment: If one is true and other is false, if will return the true value for in the column where it is true and the false value in the column where it is false. Re: how vlookup works with an array instead of a single digit in the index position, I thought I would test that by doing this: =vlookup(A13,'Sheet 2'!A11:B20,{2;2}), but that doesn't do anything other than return the value one cell to the right of the search_key in the range.

Comment: I did figure out that I needed to enclose it in "=ArrayFormula", which copied the matching value down two rows—{2;2} for second row, copied twice—or across two rows in the case of {2,2}. Taking that info, I am getting closer.

Comment: I entered this formula into cell C13 after adding Service 4: =SUMPRODUCT(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A13,'Sheet 2'!A11:K,IF(RIGHT(C2:C4)="1",{2;2;2},IF(RIGHT(C2:C4)="2",{5;5;5},IF(RIGHT(C2:C4)="3",{8;8;8},IF(RIGHT(C2:C4)="4",{11;11;11},)) )),0))) And things work well, but if I change the position of Employee 1 on sheet two (for example, switch Employee 1 and 2 and their rates in J:K), the sum is off. Hmmm. So close, I think...

Comment: VLOOKUP looks up A11:K. I changed the order in column J:K.

Order was:

Employee 1 $300.00
Employee 2 $1,500.00

Now it's:

Employee 2 $1,500.00
Employee 1 $300.00

I am getting the sum including the top row in both cases. It doesn't seem to be changing with the position of the matching value.

Comment: Should be anywhere it shows up (SO... 1, 4, 6, 10), right? and then returning the value to the right of that? Maybe I'm not understanding.

Comment: Oh wow. I think I get what you're saying. Let me try that out.

Comment: Okay that all makes sense. Unfortunately, Employee 1 will show up in different positions depending on the scenario.

Comment: That's what I tried to do, and couldn't get it to work. Here's what I came up with: =SUMPRODUCT(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A13,'Sheet 2'!A11:B,IF(RIGHT(C2:C4)="1",{2;2;2},),VLOOKUP(A13,'Sheet 2'!D11:E,IF(RIGHT(C2:C4)="2",{2;2;2},),VLOOKUP(A13,'Sheet 2'!G11:H,IF(RIGHT(C2:C4)="3",{2;2;2},),VLOOKUP(A13,'Sheet 2'!J11:K,IF(RIGHT(C2:C4)="4",{2;2;2},)))))),0) Will try again a little later. Thanks for everything.

Comment: Thanks for everything. Really appreciated.